# Fetch scaled product thumbnails through REST API

Tags: api, rest-api, thumbnail

In Magento 2 I see that the REST API only provides the path to the originally uploaded images. I would like to be able to use Magento's scaled thumbnails directly in my headless store front.

Ideally I want to modify the API so I get a path to the cached, scaled version of the thumbnail in addition to the original image. If the image is not already scaled, I would like it to happen automatically. I wonder if anyone has done anything like this before?

I don't really understand why this isn't a part of the API. Do people usually download the original image and scale/cache it in the front end system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento's API provides access to the non-formatted / almost-raw data and functionalities. It's up to you how you'll use it to solve your puzzle.
More information about that topic:

[Magento 2 as Headless solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161470/magento-2-as-a-headless-solution/161944#161944)

If you want to make API call and fetch Magento's cached image, take a look here:

[Magento 2 REST API Get Thumbnail image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123447/magento-2-rest-api-get-thumbnail-image-url#144668)