# magento 2 rest api : get cart items with images

Tags: magento2, cart, api, magento-2.1, rest-api

In rest api, I am using "/rest/V1/guest-carts/e3e1fd447e0e315dd761942cf949ce5d/items" method to get the magento cart items. It works well and the result is

```
  [
    {
      "item_id": 100,
      "sku": "abc-1",
      "qty": 1,
      "name": "Product one",
      "price": 19,
      "product_type": "simple",
      "quote_id": "e3e1fd447e0e315dd761942cf949ce5d"
    },
    {
      "item_id": 101,
      "sku": "abc-2",
      "qty": 1,
      "name": "Product two",
      "price": 54,
      "product_type": "simple",
      "quote_id": "e3e1fd447e0e315dd761942cf949ce5d"
    }
]
```

Now I want get the images of each products in the list(Possibily a thumbnail image). Is there any way to achieve this  result?

Comment: hi @ arun ss let me know whether u got solution for this question ?

Answer (score 3):

On my point of view, you have two options

1/

Make other API calls :

- /rest/V1/products/{sku}

OR

- /rest/V1/products with search criteria params

You retrieve all product information included images such as :

```
<custom_attributes>
    <item>
        <attribute_code>thumbnail</attribute_code>
        <value>/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg</value>
    </item>
</custom_attributes>
```

2/

If you need the complete path of the image with Magento cache, you need to create or extend API.

You can based on this related post : [Magento 2 Rest Api get Thumbnail Image url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123447/magento-2-rest-api-get-thumbnail-image-url)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Steps to get Product thumbnail Image in Cart through Rest API without POST any values. It will take current thumbnail Image of a product. Rest Url :

Method : GET -> rest/V1/guest-carts/{{'cartId'}}/items

Create a module : code/Vendor_name/Module_name/

registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Hopescode_Mobileshop',
    __DIR__
);
```

create module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2018-2019 Hopescode. All rights reserved.
 */
-->

    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Hopescode_Mobileshop" setup_version="1.0.0" />
    </config>
```

create etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2018-2019 Hopescode, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">

    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface">
        <attribute code="image_url" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>

</config>
```

create etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2018-2019 Hopescode, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_load_after">
        <observer name="hopescode_mobileshop_sales_quote_load_after" instance="Hopescode\Mobileshop\Observer\ProductInterface" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create Observer: Vendor_name/Mocule_name/Observer/

ProductInterface.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2018-2019 Hopescode, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Hopescode\Mobileshop\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory as ProductRepository;
    use Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory as ProductImageHelper;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface as StoreManager;
    use Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation as AppEmulation;
    use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionFactory;

    class ProductInterface implements ObserverInterface
    {   
        /**
         * @var ObjectManagerInterface
         */
        protected $_objectManager;

        /**
         * @var ProductRepository
         */
        protected $productRepository;

        /**
         *@var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
         */
        protected $productImageHelper;

        /**
         *@var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
         */
        protected $storeManager;

        /**
         *@var \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
         */
        protected $appEmulation;

        /**
         * @var CartItemExtensionFactory
         */
        protected $extensionFactory;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
         * @param ProductRepository $productRepository
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
         * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
         * @param \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
         * @param CartItemExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
            ProductRepository $productRepository,
            ProductImageHelper $productImageHelper,
            StoreManager $storeManager,
            AppEmulation $appEmulation,
            CartItemExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
        ) {
            $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
            $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
            $this->productImageHelper = $productImageHelper;
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->appEmulation = $appEmulation;
            $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
        }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer, string $imageType = NULL)
        {
            $quote = $observer->getQuote();

           /**
             * Code to add the items attribute to extension_attributes
             */
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
                $product = $this->productRepository->create()->getById($quoteItem->getProductId());
                $itemExtAttr = $quoteItem->getExtensionAttributes();
                if ($itemExtAttr === null) {
                    $itemExtAttr = $this->extensionFactory->create();
                }


                $imageurl =$this->productImageHelper->create()->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->setImageFile($product->getThumbnail())->getUrl();



                $itemExtAttr->setImageUrl($imageurl);
                $quoteItem->setExtensionAttributes($itemExtAttr);
            }
            return;
        }

        /**
         * Helper function that provides full cache image url
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
         * @return string
         */
        protected function getImageUrl($product, string $imageType = NULL)
        {
            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

            $this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
            $imageUrl = $this->productImageHelper->create()->init($product, $imageType)->getUrl();

            $this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();

            return $imageUrl;
        }

    }
```

Output :

```
[
    {
        "item_id": 5,
        "sku": "samplepro",
        "qty": 1,
        "name": "samplepro",
        "price": 1500,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "quote_id": "3f260b6e818d2fe56894ed6222e433f8",
        "extension_attributes": {
            "image_url": "http://localhost/dashboard/myapi/pub/media/catalog/product/cache//beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/n/u/nutro_crunchy_real_apple.jpg"
        }
    }
]
```

Before checking your out put, If you installed the correct method you can check your var/generation/Magento/Quote/Api/Data/CartItemExtension.php has the value like this:

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Quote\Api\Data;

/**
 * Extension class for @see \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface
 */
class CartItemExtension extends \Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject implements \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionInterface
{
    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getImageUrl()
    {
        return $this->_get('image_url');
    }

    /**
     * @param string $imageUrl
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setImageUrl($imageUrl)
    {
        $this->setData('image_url', $imageUrl);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for Magento v2.4.5

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I used the searchCriteria to get all products image paths using the sku of each product in the cart. It is done with just a single query for better performance, so there is just a single contact with the database. It is a better approach than making each call for each sku.

```
$productSearchUrl = "https://mobileapp.mymagento.com.ng/rest/V1/products?";

$max = sizeof($json['items']);

for ($i =0; $i < $max; $i++){

$value = $json['items'][$i]['sku'];
$productSearchUrl .= "searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][$i][field]=sku".
    "&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][$i][value]=$value&".
    "searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][$i][condition_type]=eq&";
}

$productSearchUrl=rtrim($productSearchUrl,"& ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cann use this link

```
http://yourmagentodomain.com/rest/V1/products/{SKU}/media
```

instead of

```
https://mobileapp.mymagento.com.ng/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][$i][field]=sku".
    "&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][$i][value]=$value&".
    "searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][$i][condition_type]=eq&"
```

this big one.

Comment: After add this module show error in cmd -
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below PHP script if you want to get product image data in the cart using "customer id".

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require '../../app/bootstrap.php'; // Change it as per your file location

$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$quote = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_id); // Change $customer_id as per your customer id
$quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
$result = array();
// get base url
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$base_url = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
$cutoff = explode("/", $base_url);
$burl = 'http://' . $cutoff[2];// Change it as per your base url
if (count($quoteItems) > 0) {
    foreach ($quoteItems as $oneItem) {
        $productData = $objectManager->get('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($oneItem->getId());
        $pimages = array();
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productData->getProductId());
        $productimages = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
        foreach ($productimages as $productimage) { 
            array_push($pimages, $productimage['url']);
        }
        $result[] = [
            'item_id' => $oneItem->getId(),
            'product_id' => $productData->getProductId(),
            'sku' => $oneItem->getSku(),
            'qty' => $oneItem->getQty(),
            'name' => $oneItem->getName(),
            'price' => $oneItem->getPrice(),
            'product_type' => $oneItem->getProductType(),
            'quote_id' => $oneItem->getQuoteId(),
            'image' => $pimages,
        ];
    }
}

json_encode($result);

?>
```